# Why does an optional in fast enumeration cause an infinite loop?

Tags: swift

Evaluating the following code, I would expect a single printing of `Hello World`. Instead, it causes an infinite loop. Can someone explain why?

```
let array = ["what"]
for text: String? in array {
    print("Hello World")
}
```

(Removing the optional `?` obviously makes it print only once)

Comment: That's a nice observation skills :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is an unexpected result, but it is happening because of the way Swift `for in` loops work under the hood.

`for in` takes a variable and a `Sequence`.  Swift calls `makeIterator()` on the `Sequence` to get an `IteratorProtocol` which returns successive items when `next()` is called on the iterator.  `next()` returns an *Optional* so that it can return `nil` when all of the items have been exhausted.

In a normal case, you receive the non-optional values and Swift continues giving them out until `nil` is received in which case the loop ends.

This is the equivalent of your code when you don't use an *optional*:

```
let array = ["what"]
var iter = array.makeIterator()
while let text = iter.next() {
    print("Hello World")
}
```

The *optional binding* (`while let`) fails when `iter.next()` returns `nil` and the loop ends.

In your case, you have said that you will explicitly receive `nil` values (by declaring your loop variable as an *optional*), so when `next()` is called on the iterator and it is out of values, it hands you a `nil` which you graciously receive and the loop continues.  The iterator continues to hand out `nil` and you continue to take them, and you have an infinite loop.

This is the equivalent of your code when you use an *optional*:

```
let array = ["what"]
var iter = array.makeIterator()
while let text: String? = iter.next() {
    print("Hello World")
}
```

In this case, the *optional binding* always works because `text` can receive the `nil`.

[This blog](https://swiftrocks.com/swift-sequence-inside-the-compiler-how-for-loops-work) gives a nice detailed explanation of what is happening under the hood with Swift `for in` loops.

Comment: Yes that's pretty detailed! I would simply just say that optional binding always succeded and return nil to the "for" loop. So infinite...

Answer (score 1):

I say this is a bug within the Swift compiler. The array is inferred as `[String]`, so a for-in loop should not allow iterating over `String?`.

If you explicitly declare the array as `[String?]`, then everything works as expected:

```swift
let array: [String?] = ["what"]
for text: String? in array {
    print("Hello World")
}
```