# swift syntax fix for JSON display loop

Tags: json, swift

I'm getting back into Swift after several years break, and some of the syntax has been lost to me. I am hoping for a quick indication on why the execution does not finish the for loop.

When I execute, after it displays Xcode just sits at using up resources without the program ending. (There should be a "Program ended with exit code: 9" at the bottom of the output if the console application finished.)

```
// v1 = <input JSON string at bottom of post>
let v2 = Utility.stringToJson(v1)! as! [String:AnyObject]
print(JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(v2)) // prints 'true'

if let puz = v2["Puzzle1"] {
    if let piece1 = puz["Piece_1"] {
        for case let row? in piece1 as! Array<Any> {
            for r in row as! Array<Int> {
                print(r, terminator: ",")
            }
            print("")
        }
        print("piece1") // Doesn't get here
    }
    print("puz") // Doesn't get here
}

print("Finished") // Doesn't get here
```

This is the output:

```
true
0,0,0,
0,1,0,
0,2,0,
3,0,0,
3,1,0,
3,2,0,
3,3,0,
0,0,1,
0,1,1,
0,2,1,
0,3,1,
1,2,1,
2,2,1,
3,0,1,
3,1,1,
3,2,1,
3,3,1,
```

This is the input. You can copy this below and paste it [here](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate for yourself the JSON and make it readable if for some reason you want to look more closely at the data.

```
{"Puzzle1":{"Piece_3":[[1,1,0],[2,0,3],[2,0,2],[2,0,1],[2,0,0],[2,1,0],[2,2,0],[2,3,0],[2,3,1],[2,3,2],[2,3,3],[2,2,3]],"Piece_1":[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,2,0],[3,0,0],[3,1,0],[3,2,0],[3,3,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[0,2,1],[0,3,1],[1,2,1],[2,2,1],[3,0,1],[3,1,1],[3,2,1],[3,3,1]],"Piece_4":[[0,0,2],[0,1,2],[0,2,2],[0,3,2],[1,2,2],[2,1,2],[2,2,2],[3,0,2],[3,1,2],[3,2,2],[3,3,2],[0,0,3],[0,2,3],[0,3,3],[2,1,3],[3,0,3],[3,1,3],[3,2,3],[3,3,3]],"Piece_2":[[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,0,3],[0,1,3],[1,1,3],[1,2,3],[1,3,3],[1,3,2],[1,3,1],[1,3,0],[1,2,0],[0,3,0]]}}
```

... Also, if you have a better way to more easily loop through the inner-most data of the json, I'm all ears.

In python, for example, I'd do something like this:

```
for row in v2["Puzzle1"]["Piece_1"]:
    for r in row:
        print(r, end=',')
    print("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work if you remove `?` after `case let row`:

```
if let puz = v2["Puzzle1"] {
    if let piece1 = puz["Piece_1"] {
        for case let row in piece1 as! Array<Any> { //<- No `?` after `row`
            for r in row as! Array<Int> {
                print(r, terminator: ",")
            }
            print("")
        }
        print("piece1")
    }
    print("puz")
}
print("Finished")
```

Swift runtime goes into infinite loop when using `case let row?`, I do not know why.
You may send a bug report to swift.org .

---

But I would write it as follows:

```
if let puz = v2["Puzzle1"] as? [String: [[Int]]] {
    if let piece1 = puz["Piece_1"] {
        for row in piece1 {
            for r in row {
                print(r, terminator: ",")
            }
            print("")
        }
        print("piece1")
    }
    print("puz")
}
print("Finished")
```

Better avoid using risky forced casting (`as!`), and avoid `Any` when you know the right types.

Comment: For why `row?` causes an infinite loop, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553800/why-does-an-optional-in-fast-enumeration-cause-an-infinite-loop) might be helpful.

Comment: much appreciated